# UploadItem: How to get event when file is successfully Uploaded?

Tags: file-upload, struts, smartgwt

I'm new to SmartGWT. I'm using SmartGWT(LGPL) 2.2 with FF 3.6.
I've done the file upload module in my GWT-Ext project successfully. In that I was using a **FormPanel** & a **FileUpload** control. After the file is uploaded I handled the event like this:

**Code:**

```
formPanel.addFormListener(new FormListenerAdapter(){

   @Override
   public void onActionComplete(Form form, int httpStatus,
     String responseText) {
    MessageBox.alert("Succesful");
   }
   @Override
   public void onActionFailed(Form form, int httpStatus,
     String responseText) {
    MessageBox.alert("Failed");
   }

  });
```

I used Struts to send request to my Action Class & redirect it back to the listener like this:

**Code:**

```
 <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
  <action name="FileUploadAction" class="com.nextenders.server.actions.FileUploadAction" >
    <result name="success" type="redirect">SUCCESS</result>
   <result name="fail">FAIL</result>
   <result name="none">NONE</result>
   <result name="blank">BLANK</result>
   <result name="size">SIZE</result>
  </action>
 </package>
```

I'm using **DynamicForm** and **UploadItem** of SmartGWT.
can anyone tell me if there is a similar functionality like `formPanel.addFormListener()` in **DynamicForm** of SmartGWT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no in built callback available for this.
You need to create some code to implement callback feature.

You can get some idea

http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=5477